# CMake boost libraries windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, boost, cmake

I am trying to use boost libraries in my windows c++ project.

When I use my CMakefile from msvc2017 I get

> Unable to find the requested Boost libraries. 1>  1>   Boost version:
>   1.65.1 1>  1>   Boost include path: C:/Users/Nagamo_s/CLionProjects/untitled3/deps/Boost 1>  1>   Could
>   not find the following Boost libraries: 1>  1>           boost_system
>   1>  1>   No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set
>   BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the 1>   directory containing Boost libraries or
>   BOOST_ROOT to the location of 1>   Boost.

But these CMake flags are set.
I activated findboost debug flag to understand why it can't find the libraries.

It looks like CMake's findboost() is trying to find files named like

> "boost_system-vc141-mt-1_65_1"

but my files are named like

> "libboost_system-vc141-mt-1_65_1"

They have a "lib" prefix.

Do you think it is the reason why CMake doesn't find the libraries ?

Comment: _"They have a "lib" prefix"_ I don't know if this is related, but the `lib` prefix is actually omitted when using the `-l` compiler flag.

Comment: @user0042 Oh it must fail for another reason then.

Comment: Probably, yes ...

Comment: What is called `libx` on Linux is generally named `x.lib` on Windows. The prefix is turned into a file name extension.

Comment: Would be nice to see your CMakeLists.txt and/or how you're setting `BOOST_ROOT`

Comment: Also, state how you built boost.  Perhaps show a partial directory listing of boost build outputs.